# SQLite extracting day from date issue

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I have a DATE field in my database with format 'YYYY-MM-DD'. Now I want to extract only 'day' from that day i.e. 'DD'. My table name is 'date' and the column name where date is stored is 'lastDonated'. How do i do it... please look these codes for more details.

```
public String day() {
    String b = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "???(what to place in here?)";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    b = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lastDonated"));

    c.moveToNext();

    return b;

}
```

I only have one row in the database

Comment: i only have one row in the database

Answer (score 1):

Use this query

```
SELECT strftime('%d', YourDateColumn) AS SomeAlias FROM YourTable
```

And get the value like this

```
b = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("SomeAlias"));
```

Reference: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: error was thrown saying no such function as strf... However i instead got all the result and used carat and converted it to integer

Comment: ... did you properly spell `strftime`? And I obviously used example names for the column and the table.

Comment: i did but all it said is no function strftime

Comment: i am new to android so i have no idea which one

Comment: i tested it on kitkat so i assume it isn't that old

Comment: Are you using the correct datetime format? i.e.: `2015-08-30`?

Comment: i did check but still it doesn't work...app fails in start........ is there other way like using any other format instead of date?.... i used date as my format in database....